# Grep exact line without any leading characters

Tags: bash

I am trying to grep a value from a file but unable to grep the desired line

file inp.txt contains

```
0:235
11:233
10:5
24:2
20:13
```

I am trying to get the value next to 0: but when i do grep "0:" the output is

```
0:235
10:5
20:13
```

The desired output is

```
0:235
```

which grep parameters will help me in capturing this?

Comment: Use anchor `grep '^0:' file`

Comment: Excellent!!
That really solved the problem @anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep` you can use start anchor:

```
grep '^0:' file
```

This will print a line that starts with `0:` i.e. `0:235`

However if you want to print 2nd field only then better to use `awk`:

```
awk -F ':' '$1 == 0{print $2}' file

235
```